# Is "Applications open on December 15th" correct grammar?

Tags: grammar

For a signup form for an online course, is it correct to say "Applications open on December 15th", or should it be "Application opens on December 15th"? Both look a little funny to me.

Comment: I think it would be better to say 'Applications invited from . . . .'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second, "Application opens on December 15th" is more idiomatic.

The word "application" here can be seen to be a shorter form of **"The application process"** - it looks funny to you because it's a little bit ungrammatical, I think.  As I said, it's a contraction.

On the other hand, if you say "applications", plural, that sounds like you are talking about the applications which are submitted, ie the things sent in by the people who are applying.  These are not opened on December the 15th, and are not what is being referred to.

Here's an example of the second: *"Application opens Jan 1st"*

http://www.central-scholarship.org/application-opens-jan-1st/